# Conceptual way of understanding what material 'does' at critical angle

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, plane-wave

I would like a conceptual way of understanding how a material behaves at the critical angle.  So why does it all reflect?  I can see why it reflects in the maths, but conceptually, it doesn't make that much sense to me, especially the evanescent wave.  Is the material basically acting like a lossless dielectric that absorbs the energy and then spits it back out?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the key point to see here is that, before you hit the critical angle, you aren't completely reflecting or completely refracting--the ratio of reflection to refraction just approaches 1 as you approach the critical angle.

Comment: Yeah I see that, I'm just wondering what happens in the material when it all reflects, and why would there be an angle at which it all reflects.

Comment: The way I understand it, when the wave strikes a medium border at greater than critical angle, it crosses the border and is refracted such that it has to cross the medium border once more($r>90^{\circ}$), and it is refracted once more, which makes it look like it has reflected from the border. I don't know the validity of this logic, that's why I'm waiting for someone else to verify this.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Yes, I don't know how valid that is either!  Hopefully we shall see!